# issue with using facade method in NGRX in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, facade

I am working with NGRX and facade. I am facing some issues. When i called  **getLedgerAccountTypes()** method of **facade** it make **api reques**t and give back **response**. but issue is that I cannot use  **.pipe().subscribe()** with it and I can not assign the data to variable in a component. On the other hand, I have **getLedgerAccountTypes$()** with which I can use **.pipe().subscribe()** but it does not make api request and select from the state. I need a method which can make api request, get a response and I can assign the data to a variable in a component. I have attach my code. please see my code and let me know how can I fix it.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.facade.getLedgerAccountTypes();
    this.facade
      .getLedgerAccountTypes$()
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe((response: LedgerAccountTypeDef) => (this.ledgerAccountTypes = response.data));
  }
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

import { FieldUsageType } from '../../../../shared/enums/field-usage-type';
import {
  LedgerAccountTypeDef
} from '../../../../shared/model/cashbook-def.interface';
import * as fromActions from './add-new-ledger-account.actions';
import * as fromSelectors from './add-new-ledger-account.selectors';
import { AddNewLedgerAccountState } from './add-new-ledger-account.state';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AddNewLedgerAccountFacade {
  constructor(private store$: Store<AddNewLedgerAccountState>) {}

  getLedgerAccountTypes(): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(new fromActions.GetLedgerAccountTypesRequest());
  }

  getLedgerAccountTypes$(): Observable<LedgerAccountTypeDef> {
    return this.store$.select(fromSelectors.ledgerAccountTypesSelector);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code with `RxJs` `of` you will wrap your first call in an `Observable` right after you will call the select from the store by using a `switchMap` and Finally the subscribe with you logic.

```
of(this.facade.getLedgerAccountTypes())
       .pipe(
         switchMap(() => this.facade.getLedgerAccountTypes$()),
         takeWhile(() => this.alive)
       )
.subscribe((response: LedgerAccountTypeDef) => (this.ledgerAccountTypes = response.data));
```